# How does flagging work with "inform moderator flags remaining" number?

Tags: support, moderation, flagging

I understand that there is a limited number of flags a person can use at any given point in time, that makes perfect sense, but what exactly is the setup for this?

Do you have 10 lifetime unless (for example) a moderator gives you one back for accepting your flag? Do they come back over time?

Info that helps to make flagging/moderating more clear as a whole is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from stackoverflow main meta ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts)):

> **How many flags do I have?**
>
> When you start out you are alloted 10 flags per-day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per-day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly.

It would seem that - at low levels - one bonus per-day flag use is added any time a flag is deemed helpful. I don't know if there is some sort of dimishing return on the long run (ie: the more you are close to the 100 flag/day cap, the more helpful flag you need to increase the counter).

EDIT: based on some research, it would seems that the system still uses the old flag weight variable to calculate the available flag per day count. I can confirm that the flag weight indeed had a not-linear grow rate (cap is/was 740 if I'm not mistaken, but at about 500 it would start to grow at a less than linear rate). I suppose that it is still the same... maybe someone has the complete formula.

Comment: Great thanks! How do you find that (and similar) links? doesn't seem immediately apparent, or maybe I'm just missing something

Comment: @Zork A lot of time the answer is already on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and since SharePoint is a part of the StackExchange network the answers there usually apply here as well. However, feel free to ask questions in Meta here as well and we can help you with the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, however I was referring to that specific link (http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts), I am just trying to determine how that was located, so that I could use the same process for similar types of questions. I understand that i can search through existing questions, but I don't see how you would find a wiki like that.

Comment: I found it on the [privileges page](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges) - flag post privilege. There is a link to the page in the user menu that it is displayed when you hover on the little arrow beside your name on the site header. Notice that the privilege link does not appear while on meta.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, that will definitely help me find this type of thing in the future!